# Storing file by creating datefolders and saving inside it

Tags: c#, excel, console-application

I want to store excel file Inside date folder which I will create dynamically. So I wrote the code Like below

```
public void ExportExcel(string strWorkbookName, DataSet ds)
    {
        string strFilePath = "";
        string strDateFolder = "";
        try
        {
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);
                //wb.SaveAs(ConfigurationRead.GetAppSetting("ReportDirectory") + "Report.xlsx");
                strDateFolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
                strFilePath = ConfigurationRead.GetAppSetting("ReportDirectory") + "\\" + strDateFolder + "\\" + "Report.xlsx";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But even the folder is not created and I get error as

> cannot implicitly convert type system io directoryinfo to string

at line:-

`strDateFolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));`

Comment: `strDataFolder` is of type `string` and `CreateDirectory` returns type `DirectoryInfo`.

Comment: @Fratyx: so how should I make it work ?

Comment: Something like that: `strDateFolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")).Name;`

Comment: But your code would only work if the result of `GetAppSetting("ReportDirectory") ` is your current directory.

Comment: @Fratyx: Yes, now I am not getting that error. But the Date folder is not created..why ?? any special reason. Yes that is current directory only

Comment: You create your directory in the current working directory where your process is running

Comment: oh, so how should I create the directory then and save the file??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166526/discussion-between-bnn-and-fratyx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like that:

```
string reportDirectory = ConfigurationRead.GetAppSetting("ReportDirectory");
strDateFolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(
    Path.Combine(reportDirectory, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))).Name;
strFilePath = Path.Combine(reportDirectory, strDateFolder, "Report.xlsx");
```

Hope this works. Could not fully check it.

Comment: hi are you their ?

Comment: Does this path exist? Which command causes the exception? I can't tell you anything about the access rights you have on your network. Maybe you are not allowed to write to your ReportDirectory.

Comment: please come on chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166526/discussion-between-bnn-and-fratyx